# phpunit: pass when single test is run, fails when all tests are run

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the problem that a specific test runs when I execute only this test. When I run all the tests together this test fails. Running from within NetBeans or from the command line has the same result.

The thing which is unique about this test compared to other tests in my suite is that it takes a file from a resources folder and then copies it to a test folder (which is created in the the beginning of the test and destroyed at the end).

I thought it was a problem with relative/absolute paths, but when I dump the source and target folders they are the same.

This is the problematic code (fails on the copy-statement):

```
public function testRemoveRequirementFileValid()
{
    $dbName = 'TRHUtilTest';
    $reqID = 1;
    $userID = 14;
    $trhVersionID = 3;

    //create the database
    DBCreator::CreateProjectDatabaseAndTables($dbName);
    DB::setConnectionInfo($dbName);

    $fileName = 'example.png';
    $sourceFolder = dirname(__FILE__).'\TRHUtilResources\\';
    $targetLink = '../'.FolderDefine::GetFolder('TRH_RequirementLink', $dbName).$trhVersionID.'/'.$reqID.'/';
    FileUtil::MKDirs($targetLink);
    $targetFolder = FolderDefine::GetFolder('TRH_RequirementFile', $dbName).$trhVersionID.'\\'.$reqID.'\\';

    //2 debugging statements
    print PHP_EOL.'Source Folder: '.$sourceFolder.PHP_EOL;
    print PHP_EOL.'Target Folder: '.$targetFolder.PHP_EOL;
    copy($sourceFolder.$fileName, $targetFolder.$fileName);

    $file = new File();
    $file->setName($fileName);
    $file->setLocation($targetLink);
    $file->save();
    $fileID = $file->getID();

    //create the link between a requirement and a file
    TRHUtil::RequirementFileLink($reqID, $fileID, $userID);

    //assert that there is one record, then check the structure and then the contents
    $this->assertEquals(1, DB::getRecordCount($dbName.'.files_reqs'));
    $this->assertEquals(1, TRHUtil::RequirementFileLinkPresent($reqID, $dbName));
    $this->assertEquals(1, TRHUtil::RequirementFileLinkCheck($reqID, $fileID, $dbName));
    $this->assertEquals(1, count(TRHUtil::GetRequirementFileLinkID($reqID, $dbName)));

    TRHUtil::RemoveRequirementFile($reqID, $dbName, $trhVersionID);

    //assert that the records about this file are removed and that the folder where the file was staying is also removed
    $this->assertEquals(0, DB::getRecordCount($dbName.'.files_reqs'));
    $this->assertEquals(0, TRHUtil::RequirementFileLinkPresent($reqID, $dbName));
    $this->assertEquals(0, TRHUtil::RequirementFileLinkCheck($reqID, $fileID, $dbName));
    $this->assertEquals(0, TRHUtil::GetRequirementFileLinkID($reqID, $dbName));
    $this->assertEquals(0, is_dir($targetFolder));

    //remove the project folder
    $projectFolder = FolderDefine::GetFolder('ProjectRoot', $dbName);
    FileUtil::RRMDir($projectFolder);
}
```

The debugging statements then give:

```
Source Folder: D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DTS\tests\util\TRHUtilResources\
Target Folder: D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DTSfiles\TRHUtilTest\trh\reqs\3\1\
```

In the output window of NetBeans I also see the following:
`copy(D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DTSfiles\TRHUtilTest\trh\reqs\3\1\example.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

However this folder is created before. Worth noting here is that the error about the copy-statement only shows the second parameter and not there are no quotes around this parameter.

Comment: You need to show your problematic test, and how it fails, to get help. It sounds like test pollution (tests which either affect global state causing a later test to fail, or start from an assumed state instead of ensuring the test scenario is as expected before performing "the test").

Comment: What fail means exactly?

Comment: @AD7six I added the problematic code

Comment: @LajosVeres: I mean that the test result is failed. I added a message which appears in the output window

Comment: @AD7six: I know it's not a complete unit test, I just placed the lines here which are causing the trouble (the full test is 49 lines). The assert statements come later in the test function.

Comment: I agree with @AD7six. Could you post the code for the test? (Even if it's 49 lines long; that's what scrollbars are for. :-) ) In particular, it would be helpful to see the code that creates the directory.

Comment: @Lilshieste: I added the full code of the unit test, although many lines aren't relevant.

Comment: What you have there is pretty confusing,  and doesn't look like a unit test.  If your code fails to copy a folder whilst setting up - that's just a "normal" problem for you to debug. E.g are the paths right ( DTSfiles?) ? _do_ the source and destination folders exist immediately before you call copy? Not much anyone can do to help you here.

Comment: As @AD7six indicated, you would benefit from refactoring this code to be more like a [unit test](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/a-unit-test-should-test-only-one-thing.html "Unit tests test one thing"). For example, a problem in `FileUtil::MKDirs` could cause this test to fail, even though *that* isn't what you're testing. As for the immediate problem, try including a check to see if that directory actually exists before you perform the copy. It's entirely possible that the directories are still in the process of being created by the time you try to copy the file over.

Comment: @Lilshieste: thanks, the problem was not in FileUtil::MKDirs (this function was present already for a long time and I have other unit tests for this), but the directory passed to this function was wrong (see below). Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to some additional debugging statements I added after the latest comment of users @AD7six and @Lilshieste.

To create the target folder I used the commands:

```
$targetLink = '../'.FolderDefine::GetFolder('TRH_RequirementLink', $dbName).$trhVersionID.'/'.$reqID.'/';
FileUtil::MKDirs($targetLink);
```

This means the following folder was created: ../../../DTSfiles/TRHUtilTest/trh/reqs/3/1/

However, it should be:

```
$targetFolder = FolderDefine::GetFolder('TRH_RequirementFile', $dbName).$trhVersionID.'\\'.$reqID.'\\';
FileUtil::MKDirs($targetFolder);
```

Which corresponds to the folder: D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DTSfiles\TRHUtilTest\trh\reqs\3\1\

Since the start location of running this one unit test is different as the root folder where all the tests are residing is different (the root-test-folder is two directory levels deeper) the target folder was indeed created, but at a wrong level.

Thanks to all for the support.

Comment: Glad you hear you found the problem. Now that things are working, this is a great opportunity to [start refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/articles/workflowsOfRefactoring/). :-)

Comment: You have a good point, but in fact this test is more an integration test than a unit test (all other functions used in here (e.g. FileUtil::MKDirs) where already covered by other, much smaller unit tests).

Comment: You're right, and you should definitely keep this test. There's a design underneath this test that's waiting to get out, though, illustrated by the difficulties you were encountering. But that's off-topic from your question, so my apologies for the distraction.